# My break statement unintentionally interrupt my loop, how should I fix it?

Tags: ruby

I was looping some music notes and wanted it to stop looping when I enter. However, the loop cycle stops when it encounters the code:

```
stop = gets
if stop == "\n"
    puts "You have stopped listening, どうして？"
    break
end`
```

that only intended to break when receive the 'enter' input
Here is the full code:

```
a=0
loop do
    if a+=1
        puts "♪"
        sleep(0.1)
    end
    if a+=2
        puts " ♫"
        sleep(0.2)
    end
    if a+=3
        puts"   ♪"
        sleep(0.3)
    end
    if a+=4
        puts"    ♫"
        sleep(0.4)
    end
    if a+=5
        puts"     ♪"
        sleep(0.5)
    end
    if a+=6
        puts"    ♪"
        sleep(0.6)
    end
    if a+=7
        puts"  ♪"
        sleep(0.5)
    end
    if a+=8
        puts"♪"
        sleep(0.4)
    end
stop = gets
  if stop == "\n"
    puts "You have stopped listening, どうして？"
    break
  end
end
```

I know the loop stopped after a+=8 because it ran into the break command, thus, I tried isolate the code block containing break but it was not the way.

Comment: "I know the loop stopped after a+=8 because it ran into the break command" - no, it didn't. It blocks on `gets`, waiting for your user input. Then, if you press just enter, it breaks the loop. But if you add any other characters before enter, it will not break the loop and will do another iteration.

Comment: I see sir @SergioTulentsev, I will work around this new information. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Schutzen can you explain how your code is supposed to work? When you say _"unintentionally interrupt my loop"_ – what's the expected behavior? BTW, those `if a+=...` conditions seem rather pointless. They just increment `a` by increasing values but `a` is never used.

Comment: Hi there sir @Stefan, I will try my best to elaborate on the matter with my limited knowledge. I expected the loop of musical notes to stop when it encountered the entered input which it actually did thanks to the correction of sir Sergio Tulenstev. I initially thought that the iteration stopped for no reason but in actuality, it was blocked by the 'gets' statement to wait for user input. Regarding the if `a+=`, in my mind, I thought I could use the odd and even `if a` (e,g,` a+=1` being odd, `a+=2` being even) to create musical pattern. I hope this makes any sense and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to keep printing those music notes until the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd>.

You are facing two problems:

1. you can't gather any input while your program is `sleep`-ing
2. calling `gets` will block (i.e. pause) your program until input is available

In order to gather input via `gets` while still printing your notes (and occasional sleeping) in a loop, I would probably utilize a separate thread to perform both tasks concurrently:

```
music_thread = Thread.new do
  loop do
    puts "♪"
    sleep(0.1)

    puts " ♫"
    sleep(0.2)

    puts "   ♪"
    sleep(0.3)

    puts "    ♫"
    sleep(0.4)

    puts "     ♪"
    sleep(0.5)

    puts "    ♪"
    sleep(0.6)

    puts "  ♪"
    sleep(0.5)

    puts "♪"
    sleep(0.4)
  end
end

gets
music_thread.exit
puts "You have stopped listening, どうして？"
```

In the above (simplified) code a new [`Thread`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Thread.html) is created which just prints notes in a loop indefinitely. The main thread then reads a line of input via `gets`, which will block the main thread at that point until the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd> (the music thread will keep running). Once `gets` returns, the main thread stops `music_thread` via [`exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Thread.html#exit-method), prints a message and the program is finished.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and for fixing my code sir, this is the first time I have ever heard about the Thread. class so I will look it up for more info.